# mojolicious assign an array to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, perl, mojolicious

I have an array reference ($sections) in the stash.  I'm trying to dereference this and assign it to a javascript array but nothing that i try works.

for example

```
%= javascript begin
    var list = <%== $sections %>;
    etc...
% end
```

leads to list equaling ARRAY0x23456 (which is correct since $sections is a ref)

```
%= javascript begin
    var list = <%== @$sections %>;
    etc...
% end
```

Assigns the array length to list (which is correct since list is treated as a scalar assignment).

```
%= javascript begin
    var list = <%== $sections %>.slice();
    etc...
% end
```

gives an error because $sections is a ref

```
%= javascript begin
    var list = <%== @$sections %>.slice();
    etc...
% end
```

Arguably is the most likely candidate but resolves to [array.length].slice() (e.g. 3.slice()), and fails.

How can I do this?

EDIT;
I've managed to do this by forming a string with the array values in it within the stash and then creating the array I want from this.

e.g. stash contains the string 5,6,7,8 in $string
within the javascript i can then do

```
array = [ <%= $string %> ];
```

I'd still be interested to know if there is a way to do this using the arrayref in the stash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment:

```
<%== @$sections %>
```

is equivalent to:

```
print scalar @$sections;
```

...so that is why you are getting the array length: an array in scalar context is the length of the array.

To get a javascript array, you have to replace <...> below with something that will cause the output to look like a js array:

```
print scalar <....>;
```

You can do something like this:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/test' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->stash(sections => [1, 2, 3]);

    {
        local $" = ", ";  #The value that gets inserted between array elements 
                          #when an array is interpolated into a string. The default
                          #value is a space.
        $c->render('template1');
    } 
    # $" gets reset to its previous value here
};

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ template1.html.ep
%= javascript begin
  var arr =  <%== "[@$sections]" %>;
  console.log(arr[0]);
% end

Examine your browser's javascript console....
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about S" - that's also useful.  So the braces simply limit the scope of the assignment to $"?

Comment: @mark, `local` limits the assignment to the surrounding scope and restores the old value when that scope is exited, and the surrounding scope is delimited by the braces.  Using `local` is considered good practice when you change perl's predefined global variables.